# Is paintComponent painting before images have loaded and if so how do I fix it?

Tags: java, image, swing, nullpointerexception, paintcomponent

I am designing a cookie clicker like game. I have a class that extends JPanel and in the constructor I load some images into an Image object. But when I go to paint them in paintComponent the console start spewing NullPointerExceptions for a few seconds then stops and the window loads properly. My only guess is that the images are taking time to load and that paintComponent is trying to paint them before they have loaded entirely. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
public PanelClass() {
        frame.setSize(screenSize);
        frame.add(this);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
            buttonGraphics.start();
        try {
            background = ImageIO.read(new File("res/img/Background.png")).getScaledInstance(getWidth(), getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            steamLogo[0] = ImageIO.read(new File("res/img/SteamLogo.png")).getScaledInstance(getWidth()/5, getWidth()/5, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            for (int i = 1; i < steamLogo.length; i++) {
                steamLogo[i] = steamLogo[0].getScaledInstance(steamLogo[0].getWidth(null)-(i*2), steamLogo[0].getWidth(null)-(i*2), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            }       
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logoHitbox = new Ellipse2D.Double((getWidth()/2)-(steamLogo[0].getWidth(null)/2), (getHeight()/2)-(steamLogo[0].getHeight(null)/2), getWidth()/5, getWidth()/5);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        g.drawImage(steamLogo[curLogo], (getWidth()/2)-(steamLogo[curLogo].getWidth(null)/2), (getHeight()/2)-(steamLogo[curLogo].getHeight(null)/2), null);
        if(clicked > 1) {
            g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,155-(clicked*7)));
            g.fillOval((getWidth()/2)-(steamLogo[curLogo].getWidth(null)/2), (getHeight()/2)-(steamLogo[curLogo].getHeight(null)/2), (int)steamLogo[curLogo].getWidth(null), (int)steamLogo[curLogo].getHeight(null));
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) `frame.setVisible(true);` This should be last in the constructor.  2) `g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);` This should be `g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this);` to account for images that are loaded asynchonously, though.. 3) `ImageIO.read(..);` is a blocking method (**not** asynchronous). 4) General tip: ..

Comment: .. Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Comment: Thanks! This immediately fixed my problem.